# Create Task in Snowflake in UTC timezone

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I like to create a task in Snowflake which will run on 05 Am daily in UTC time zone. Have tried using other format but there is no luck

Answer (score 1):

The Cron Expression for 05 AM UTC should be
0 5 * * *

Make sure that you add UTC TZ in your TASK DDL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK My_task
WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON * * * * * UTC'
AS <SQL Expression>
```